# Non-editable UITextView requires double tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a UITextView and I unchecked "Editable" in IB. The text value of the text view is programmatically changed. However, the user needs to tap on the text view for it to be altered. When "Editable" is enabled, the text view requires only 1 tap to enable, but now that I've unchecked "Editable", it's requiring 2 taps to enable. How can I leave it un-editable but require only 1 tap to enable?

Comment: so you want the user to be able to 'edit' it when they tap on it? or you want the textview to update programmatically when you tap it?

Comment: Well I have a custom number keyboard made of PNG's and when I tap on the UITextView the custom keyboard is the first responder so it pops up. However, I dont want the blinking cursor to appear in the text view, and when its set on not-editable, the cursor disappears, so that's why I have it set up like this. My main goal is to hide the cursor, and this is one of the ways. But only problem is now its double tap rather tan single.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a UILabel in a UIScrollView if you want to hide the cursor and dont need cursor-related features (cursor placement, highlighting text etc).

Comment: And how would I activate the custom keyboard when the label is tapped?

Comment: Place a transparent UIButton over the UILabel

Comment: So then I could probably just do the same thing with a UITextView-just put a transparent UIButton over it?